# Weak references inside a block UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Why creates duplicate rows?

my code.
for test im return empty cell `if(indexPath.row > 0 && indexPath.row <5) return cell;`. This login should return 3 rows. 1 in top and 2 in bottom. im upload screens

```
int indexOne = 1;



VVMartCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:martCellIdentifier];

if(indexPath.row > 0 && indexPath.row <5) return cell;

cell.imageView1.image = nil;
cell.imageView2.image = nil;
cell.imageView3.image = nil;
[cell setDelegateController:self];

    __weak VVMartCell *weakCell = cell;
//////////
VVMartModel *model1 = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexOne];
[cell setModel1:model1];

    if (!model1.imageView) {
        model1.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    }

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[model1 path_package]]];

__weak VVMartModel* weakModel1 = model1;

    [cell.imageView1 setImageWithURLRequest:request
                           placeholderImage:nil
                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                        if(weakModel1)
                                        {
                                            weakModel1.imageView.image = image;
                                        }
                                        if (weakCell)
                                        {
                                            weakCell.imageView1.image = image;
                                            [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
                                        }


                                    }
                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                    }];
```

[image]

Comment: the `UICollectionView` has been developed for managing such kind of UI exactly; you should convert to it, maybe.